# Get not available data from given data using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need query:

for example: `'1','2','9','10','3','4','5','6','7','8';`

table name:getstdata

```
    ID
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    5
    7
```

Query:

```
select ID from getstdata where ID in('1','2','9','10','3','4','5','6','7','8')
```

Results:

```
'1','2','3','4','5','6','7'
```

In above data 8,9,10 not in data. I need that not available Data. Please give me solution for it.

Thank you

Comment: You cannot in this form - the values list used in WHERE must be converted to rowset.

Comment: I dont have idea on rowset...can you give some example regarding it?

Comment: Convert it to a table using `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION ...` or `VALUES ROW(1), ROW(2), ...`.

Comment: First thing first, do you have a table that stores everything? Lets say in your example, you have two tables - the first table is a Master table where it stores everything and the second table only store data only if it has occurrences.

Comment: Dear Akina, you are trying to give solution to my problem. But, Unfortunately i unable to catch you. Can you give full example based on your example UNION or on any other

Answer (score 0):

What Akina meant was to create a temp table from a query since you don't have an existing table that stores all info (what my ignored question in comment suggest).

So you have table `getstdata` and you want to get an example of number range from 1 to 10 that doesn't exist in the table `ID` column, then you make a temp table that stores a range of 1 to 10 numbers like this:

```
SELECT 1 AS T UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION 
SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10;
```

Which will give you this result:

```
+-----+
| T   |
+-----+
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
| 4   |
| 5   |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 8   |
| 9   |
| 10  |
+-----+
```

Then you make that as a sub-query and do a `LEFT JOIN` to your `getstdata` table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS T UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION 
     SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10) A 
LEFT JOIN getstdata B ON A.T=B.ID;
```

That will give you something like this:

```
+-----+------+
| T   | ID   |
+-----+------+
| 1   |  1   |
| 2   |  2   |
| 3   |  3   |
| 4   |  4   |
| 5   |  5   |
| 6   |  6   |
| 7   |  7   |
| 8   | NULL |
| 9   | NULL |
| 10  | NULL |
+-----+------+
```

In the above result, the `NULL` value is what you're looking for. Therefore you can refine the query to become like this:

```
SELECT A.T FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS T UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION 
     SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10) A 
LEFT JOIN getstdata B ON A.T=B.ID
    WHERE B.ID IS NULL;
```

This end result:

```
+-----+
| T   |
+-----+
| 8   |
| 9   |
| 10  |
+-----+
```

As you can see, that's a quick way to solve your current issue but what if the comparison that you're making is not numbers? of what if the numbers range from 1-1000? Would you rather to write `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION ... all the way to ... SELECT 999 UNION SELECT 1000;` as the sub-query? But if you're using MariaDB version 10.0.3 and above, you can easily make a range of numbers using it's built-in [sequence engine](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mariadb/mariadb_sequences.htm).

*A quick MariaDB example using sequence engine:

```
SELECT A.T FROM 
    (SELECT Seq AS T FROM seq_1_to_10) A 
LEFT JOIN getstdata B ON A.T=B.ID 
WHERE B.ID IS NULL;
```

Still, that's just a solution to compare numbers only. [Fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pShsxg47WawaUpH9uLTLeb/1).